# Creating syncable Calendar in ICS

Tags: android, calendar

I have a problem with creating a new Calendar in ICS. The Calendar should be synyable to the google Calendar. I try following:

```
            Uri calendarUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, sync_account);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");

        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, name);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0xFF008080);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, true);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);

        calendarUri = calendarUri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, sync_account)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google") // CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL
            .build();
        Uri result = activity.getContentResolver().insert(calendarUri, calendar);
```

an I get always this error (Edit: not anymore):

```
    09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243): FATAL EXCEPTION: CalendarSyncAdapterAccountMonitor
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:48)
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar.CalendarSyncAdapter.onAccountsUpdated(CalendarSyncAdapter.java:1129)
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.accounts.AccountManager$11.run(AccountManager.java:1279)
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 17:11:30.278: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
09-17 17:11:30.293: E/android.os.Debug(1989): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

What can I do with the CalendarSyncAdapterAccountMonitor, that it is not empty?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I forgot to insert the timezone, than I dont get an error at all:

```
calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
```

**If I create the syncable calendar (code snippset above), just noting happens, no error and no calendar created.**

If I change it to lokal (see following) the calendar can be created without error, even events can be added. What can I do, that a syncable calendar can be created?

```
        Uri calendarUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;

        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, sync_account);//
        //calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, name);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0xFF008080);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, sync_account);// true 
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1); // 1 for syncable, 0 for local
        //calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.DIRTY, 0);
        calendar.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

        calendarUri = calendarUri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, sync_account)//
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL) //  "com.google"
            .build();
        Uri result = activity.getContentResolver().insert(calendarUri, calendar);
```

Comment: Check if all the variables you use are not null.. We can't see that in the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a new calendar manually and parse the calendar in your app with:

```
Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars",null, null, null, null);
```

After finding the correct calendar id, you can just add/update events into it. This events will be syncable.